# Sqlite3 syntax format may not be correct

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have this sqlite3 query and for some reason it may not be structured correctly. I have inserted this into an application that I am working on in IOS6 with objective c:

```
const char *sql = "SELECT id, Wine, Rating, Photo FROM 1tbl"
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: We need more info. What happens? Are you getting a runtime error? A compile error? Either way, post the full error message.

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a single view application that has a db within using a winelist. I've made sure that the db is linked correctly however when I run the application I read that sqlite3 does not use parse and that the problem may be a sysntax or a sqlite can't parse the your query string. There might be a typo somewhere, maybe missing a comma. that is my problem

Comment: The SQL syntax is correct, the problem may be that the entity does not exist or that id doesn't have these attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Given your detailed explanation of the problem I'll just try to guess:

Your table is not called `1tbl` because it's not a valid table name.